# How to mock Axios service wrapper using JEST

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, axios, jest-fetch-mock

I'm using JEST testing framework to write test cases for my React JS application. I'm using our internal axios wrapper to make service call. I would like to mock that wrapper service using JEST. Can someone help me on this ?

```
import Client from 'service-library/dist/client';
import urls from './urls';
import { NODE_ENV, API_VERSION } from '../screens/constants';
const versionHeader = 'X-API-VERSION';
class ViewServiceClass extends Client {
  getFiltersList(params) {
    const config = {
      method: urls.View.getFilters.requestType,
      url: urls.View.getFilters.path(),
      params,
      headers: { [versionHeader]: API_VERSION },
    };
    return this.client.request(config);
  }
const options = { environment: NODE_ENV };
const ViewService = new ViewServiceClass(options);
export default ViewService;
```

Above is the Service Implementation to make API call. Which I'm leveraging that axios implementation from our internal library.

```
getFiltersData = () => {
    const params = {
      filters: 'x,y,z',
    };
    let {
      abc,
      def,
      ghi
    } = this.state;
    trackPromise(
      ViewService.getFiltersList(params)
        .then((result) => {
          if (result.status === 200 && result.data) {
            const filtersJson = result.data;
            
        .catch(() =>
          this.setState({
            alertMessage: 'No Filters Data Found. Please try after some time',
            severity: 'error',
            showAlert: true,
          })
        )
    );
  };
```

I'm using the ViewService to get the response, and I would like to mock this service. Can someone help me on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to spy your `getFiltersList` method from `ViewServiceClass` class.

Then mocking some response data (a `Promise`), something like:

```
import ViewService from '..';

const mockedData = {
  status: 'ok',
  data: ['some-data']
};

const mockedFn = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(mockedData));

let getFiltersListSpy;

// spy the method and set the mocked data before all tests execution
beforeAll(() => {
  getFiltersListSpy = jest.spyOn(ViewService, 'getFiltersList');
  getFiltersListSpy.mockReturnValue(mockedFn);
});

// clear the mock the method after all tests execution
afterAll(() => {
  getFiltersListSpy.mockClear();
});

// call your method, should be returning same content as `mockedData` const
test('init', async () => {
  const response = await ViewService.getFiltersList();
  expect(response).toEqual(mockedData);
});
```

P.D: You can pass `params` to the method, but you will need to configure as well the `mockedData` as you wish.

Comment: I have updated the question actually I'm making the API call insider `getFiltersData` method. In this case I have to spy `getFiltersData` correct ?

Comment: `getFiltersData` is in another class? Indeed, should work! Just replace in the example for your new method.

Comment: Not in different calls within same call but getFilterList is there in ViewService Class. Like I mentioned in above problem.@AdriSolid

Comment: It worked when I properly placed the beforeAll and afterAll methods in my test class.